# How to create web deploy package in VSTS/VSO Build vNext?

Tags: build, msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an automated build in Visual Studio Team Services (formerly Visual Studio Online. The solution is building correctly. How do I configure it so it will also create a web deploy package?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We enable web deploy package creation within the "Visual Studio Build" task. Simply pass the following MS Build arguments:

MSBuild Arguments: `/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=<name of your profile>`

Comment: Use /p:Password=MyPassword  to avoid commiting your password

Answer (score 20):

We use the following MSBuild Arguments: `/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"`

With these you do not need to create a new publishing profile.

Comment: I had a solution with multiple web projects and had to uncheck "Clean" to get it to work correctly.

Comment: @BurnsBA  you may have dependencies that are not building in the correct order or referenced incorrectly I am presently experiencing this issue.  I am having to correct a lot of solutions and projects to make items build correctly.